# Rails 3 -- for loop giving an Undefined method 'each'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop, nomethoderror

`Rails -v 3.2.3`

Im trying to display links inside of a table in my views
I keep getting
 `NoMethodError in Links#submissions , views/links/submissions.html.erb where line #10 raised: undefined method "each" for nil:NilClass`

heres my **submission.htm.erb**

```
<table>
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <tr valign = "top">
    <td>
      <%= link_to_remote "Up",
                        :url => { :action => 'modify_points',
                               :id => link.id,
                               :by => 1 },
                    :update => "link" + link.id.to_s %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= link_to_remote "Down",
                    :url => { :action => 'modify_points',
                              :id => link.id,
                              :by => -1 },
                    :update => "link" + link.id.to_s %>

</td>

<td>
  <b> <a href="<%= link.url %>"> <%= link.description %> </a> </b>
  (<%= if link.url =~ /(:\/\/) ([^\/]*)/ then $2 else "wrong URL" end %>) <br/>
  <span id="link"><%= link.id.to_s %>"%><%= link.points %> </span>
  points posted <%= time_ago_in_words link.created_at %> ago
</td>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

my question is.... do i need to write some code in the case that there are no links? Is this why I'm getting this error message?

Comment: Depends what @links is; if it's an association, it should be an empty array if there aren't any. How do you initialize it?

Comment: @links is initialized in **links_controller.rb** in a method called submission `@link_pages, @links = Link.page(params[:page]).per(20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, better safe than sorry if you don't know whether @links will exist in the context.

```
<% if @links.present? %>
  <% @links.each do |link|
    etc 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

etc...maybe there's some better ruby shorthand for this..if so I'm sure someone will remind us. :)